# Spring Boot - how to validate nested enteties

Tags: java, spring, validation

So lets say I have User object like this

```
@Entity
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;
    private String name;
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "address", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Address address;
}

@Entity
public class Address {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;
    private String city;
    private String country;
}
```

Now I don't want to write validation annotations in entities. What I would like to do is validate `User` in `@RestController` like this

```
@RestController
public class InvoiceController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/users/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public Invoice addInvoice(@Validated @RequestBody ValidUser user) {
        ... do stuff
    }
}
```

The validation annotations would be in `ValidUser` being like this.

```
public class ValidUser extends User {
    @NotNull
    private String name;
    @Valid
    private Address address;
}

public class ValidAddress extends Address{
    @NotNull
    private String city;
    @NotNull
    private String country;
}
```

The validation works when I remove the `address` field from the `ValidUser` but not when it is there. How can I make address validation also work?

Comment: you can create you own validator that validate the whole given object as the way you want in the controller.

Comment: Use `@Valid` annotation at the method param level instead of `@Validate` annotation and not at the field one. `@Valid` triggers Hibernate jsr303 validation

Comment: I have tried using `@Valid` and it is not working

Comment: your form objects like `ValidUser` should've the both constructors the default and the full one including all the setters&getters. Add the `Errors errors` field immediatelly after `ValidUser` param. Also, `spring-boot-starter-web` or `hibernate-validator` have to be wired as dependencies. Then, after your controller method triggered fine you can ensure wheither validation succeed by the options of the `Errors` field like `errors.hasErrors()` etc.